# Changing A Contact Form Based On A Cookie Or (Other Solution)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, contact-form-7

I have a site using Contact Form 7. One of the agents apart of this site wants their own sub-domain as a landing page.

When a user comes to that landing page, they want a cookie to be set. If a user with that cookie navigates away from the landing page and goes to the site's application page, they want the contact form on the application page to automatically select that agent (where they come from) and have the other options hidden.

Is there a viable way to do this? Javascript/jQuery/PHP is definitely not my strong suite, we don't have a back end developer and there's never any line of communication before the owner charges a client for a site they promise him.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to set the cookies from your landing page like the following:

```
setcookie("name","value",time()+$int);
/*name is your cookie's name
value is cookie's value
$int is time of cookie expires*/
```

You can then check the cookie if it exist from the contact form 7 page like the following:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["name"])) {
    // Do your stuff
    // You're from the landing page
} else {
    // You're not from the landing page
}
```